# PHP simple activation Form MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've tweaked and broke this a million times already today!
I'm basically trying to check the database for the username and activation,
if user is activated show congratulations message
if user is a user but there not activated show activate message
if they isn't a record matching user then display invalid message.
**Any help on re-coding and correcting my errors would be much appreciated, I feel like I'm just going round and round in circles!**

string(74) "UPDATE members SET Check_Activation='' WHERE Username='' AND Activation=''"

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="check-activation.php">
  <div align="center">
    <table width="35%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>Members Number</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><label>
          <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Activation Code</td>
        <td><label>:</label></td>
        <td><input name="activation_code" type="text" id="activation_code" value="<?php echo $activation_code; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
          <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Cancel">
        </label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </form>
```

This is the form

```
<?php
$db_host = "*******";
$db_name = "*******";
$db_use = "*******";
$db_pass = "*******";
$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_use, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);
$command = "UPDATE members SET Check_Activation='$activation_code' WHERE Username='$username' AND Activation='$activation_code'";
$result = mysql_query($command);
if ($result) {
echo "Congratulations. Your membership has been activated ...";
}else{
echo ("You've entered an invalid username / activation code - please retry");
}
?>
```

This is checking the database and displaying the result

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're going to have an issue with the code as you've written it - it's a valid SQL statement to perform an UPDATE that has no rows that are affected. You'll need to count how many rows were affected instead.

Comment: try to add a die after after mysql-functions to check whether databases connection ist correct `mysql_func() or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: @andrewsi mysql_query with an update statement returns true on success.

Comment: @quidage - it returns true if the query runs successfully, yes. But for example `UPDATE .. WHERE field=1 AND field=2` will run successfully and not update anything.

Comment: Can you show a final query, like: `var_dump($command);`.

Comment: `$activation_code` should maybe be `$_POST['activation_code'];`

Comment: @insertusernamehere string(74) "UPDATE members SET Check_Activation='' WHERE Username='' AND Activation=''"

Comment: @DanFromGermany I hope you mean something more like `$activation_code = sanitize($_POST['activation_code']);` as simply replacing `$activation_code` is highly vulnerable for SQL injections.

Comment: @insertusernamehere No, I mean that the variables he is using might just be empty.

Comment: @AdamWadsworth There you see, that both variables don`t hold any value. So your problem seems to be there somewhere.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yes, I get your point. But "*should maybe be*" sounds like you're encouraging him to simply replace the variables. As the OP doesn't use anything to secure the query, this may result in a security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

---

As you can see below at each step we have a verification to know if we were able to connect to the database, if the SQL query was OK, if the parameters you want to give are OK and we also take the opportunity to prevent injection with the prepared statement and we finally execute it.

Now notice how after we execute it, I verify how many rows were affected using `$update->affected_rows` to know if it was OK or not.

The affected rows, can return:

- -1 indicating that the query returned an error
- 0 indicating no records were updated
- and a number above 0, indicating how many rows were affected

Code:

```
$db_host = "*******";
$db_name = "*******";
$db_use = "*******";
$db_pass = "*******";

// Read the form values you just submitted
$username = $_POST['username'];
$activation_code = $_POST['activation_code'];

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_use,$db_pass,$db_name);
// Output an error message if it fails to connect
if($con->connect_error)
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

// Here we prepare your query and make sure it is alright
$sql = "UPDATE members SET Check_Activation = ? WHERE Username = ? AND Activation = ?";
if (!$update = $con->prepare($sql))
    die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);

// Here we define the field types with 'sss' which means string, string, string
// and also set the fields values
if (!$update->bind_param('sss', $activation_code, $username, $activation_code))
    die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $update->errno . ') ' . $update->error);

// Now we finally execute the data to update it to the database
// and if it fails we will know
if (!$update->execute())
    die('Execute failed: (' . $update->errno . ') ' . $update->error);

if ($update->affected_rows > 0)
{
    echo "Congratulations. Your membership has been activated ...";
}
else
{
    echo ("You've entered an invalid username / activation code - please retry");
}
// And finally we close the connection
$update->close();
$con->close();
```

Note the interrogation signs on the query and the `bind_param`, `s` means string and `i` means integer, [**you can read more here**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: the <?php and DB details where checked they isn't any error showing.

Comment: @AdamWadsworth that's my mistake, change `$update->affected_rows()` to `$update->affected_rows` :) just remove the parenthesis from it. I have also updated the above code to reflect the change.

Comment: Thank you very much this works a treat! Do you have Twitter or Facebook ?

Comment: @AdamWadsworth glad its all good now and sorry, I don't use social medias.

Answer (score 1):

To get the answer if any row was inserted/updated you should use [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows)

```
if (mysql_affected_rows()) {
echo "Congratulations. Your membership has been activated ...";
}else{
echo ("You've entered an invalid username / activation code - please retry");
}
```

this code can be also simplified to

```
echo mysql_affected_rows() ? "Congratulations. Your membership has been activated ..." : "You've entered an invalid username / activation code - please retry";
```

The function returns the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last query failed.

However when you get to manual there is big red box with message that **mysql_* functions are depracated** that is why you should consider using PDO or Mysqli instead.